# Using a string for variable name in dplyr top_n

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use a string variable to pass a column name into `top_n` and not getting results

```
metric <- "column_name"
top_n(df, 5, metric)
```

I have tried

```
top_n(df, 5, !!metric)
```

which didn't work either

Comment: Would help if you shared the input as well as desired output. What is `metric`? A string representing an integer e.g. `'5'`? A string representing a column name e.g `'column1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sym()` (or `as.name()` in base) to turn a string into symbol, then add `!!` to unquote it.

```
top_n(df, 5, !!sym(metric))
```